# Spring Security set CSRF in login response with new session token

Tags: spring, security, spring-security, csrf

I'm using spring security in my spring boot application.  I have a front end single page app that logs in via rest.  I have no problem logging in, but once I've logged in, my session token changes, BUT THE CSRF TOKEN DOES NOT.

Is there any way to force spring security to set the csrf token since the old token associated with the un-authenticated session token will not work with the new authenticated session token?

I'm storing the CSRF token in a cookie, and sending it back from the client in the header of every state altering request.  I can't login and logout without an intervening request (non-post) to retrieve the csrf token.  This seems like a crock.

Answer (score 2):

SO a simple solution is to redirect the login request once it's successful.  This puts the request through another loop through the security filter chain ensuring a new CSRF is added to the new session token.  A good night sleep does wonders.